# How to show progress bar in JQuery Data table while loading Data from SQL Table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery Data Table 1.10.12 to load the data  From SQL  Table to show in the JQuery Data Table . I am not using server side and its taking around 5-6 seconds to load the data into JQuery Data Table. Is there any way i can add  the Progress bar  or Processing .... message while Page loads completely.

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      //  asmx service to retrive the  data from server side
      url: '<%= ResolveUrl("ABCD.asmx/GetDetails")%>',
      method: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#example2').DataTable({
          searchHighlight: true,
          lengthChange: false,
          search: {
            smart: false
          },
          language: {
            searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
          },
          data: data,
          'columns': [{
            'data': 'FId',
            'visible': false
          }, {
            'data': 'FirmName',
            'render': function(data, type, row, meta) {
              var idc = row['FId'];
              return '<a target="_blank"         href="Firms.aspx?type=f&id=' + idc + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }
          }, {
            'data': 'ABC',
            'sortable': false
          }, {
            'data': 'DEF',
            'sortable': false
          }, {
            'data': 'GHI',
            'sortable': false
          }, {
            'data': 'City'
          }, {
            'data': 'Country'
          }, ]
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Why not try :  "processing": true,

Comment: Hi Shree,  processing: true, is not working without luck

Comment: processing: true will works if you set it before your success callback and serverSide: true. Take a look : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Hi John, I am not using Serverside processing here . I will give a try to use serverSide processing and update you.

Answer (score -1):

Append your html progress bar in ajax event called beforeSend, fake the animation by progressing lets say 10% per second. then on succes finish the animation (drag it to 100%) and detach it.

Comment: Hi Anton , Thanks for the advise .I am new to this and  any piece of code  to start would be a great help.